# 415 error when trying to "send a document for signature - from template" using Zoho Creator and DocuSign API

Tags: api, docusignapi, zoho

I'm trying to set up a Zoho Creator application that will request a signature on an Envelope created from a Template. I'm able to use [**this tool**](http://iodocs.docusign.com/?version=v2) to do it, but when I try to do the same thing using Zoho Creator's postURL() function, I get the following response from DocuSign:

```
Response Code = 415
Response Text = HTTP Error
```

[**This post**](http://community.docusign.com/t5/DocuSign-API-Integration-Ruby-Salesforce-and-Other-READ-ONLY/Docusign-Integration-With-Zoho-Application/td-p/12517a) seems to describe the exact same error.  The response given is unclear, and I can't find the documentation that is supposed to have been updated.

Here is some of my Creator code:

```
void test3()
{
// Login
username = "XXX";
usernameEmail = "XXX";
password = "XXX";
integratorKey = "XXX";
templateId = "XXX";
authenticateStr = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" + username + "</Username><Password>" + password + "</Password><IntegratorKey>" + integratorKey + "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";
loginUrl = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
loginHeaders = { "X-DocuSign-Authentication" : authenticateStr, "Accept" : "application/json" };
loginGet = getUrl(loginUrl, loginHeaders,false);
loginResponseCode = loginGet.get("responseCode");
loginResponseText = loginGet.get("responseText");          
if (loginResponseCode  !=  "200")
{
    info "Error calling webservice; status is " + loginResponseCode;
}
```

Creator can't process the response properly, so I have to clean it up here

```
loginResponseText = loginResponseText.replaceAll("\r\n","");
loginResponseText = loginResponseText.getSuffix("[");
loginResponseText = loginResponseText.getPrefix("]");
loginResponseMap = loginResponseText.toMap();
info loginResponseMap;
baseUrl = loginResponseMap.get("baseUrl");
accountID = loginResponseMap.get(("accountId"));
url = baseUrl + "/envelopes";
headers = map();
headers.put("X-DocuSign-Authentication", "{\"Username\":\"XXX\",\"Password\":\"XXX\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"XXX\"}");
requestBody2 = "{\n \"envelopeDefinition\" : \"{\n  \"-xmlns\" : \"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\",\n =\"xmlns:i\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\",\n \"emailSubject\": \"test email subject\",\n  \"emailBlurb\": \"test email blurb\",\n  \"templateId\": \"1D489D22-55D9-4320-8C16-28DE11C4AB09\",\n  \"status\": \"created\",\n  \"messageLock\": \"false\"\n}}";
envelopePOST = postUrl(url,requestBody2,headers,false);
postResponseCode = envelopePOST.get("responseCode");
postResponseText = envelopePOST.get("responseText");
info "envelopePOST = " + envelopePOST;
info "Response Code = " + postResponseCode;
info "Response Text = " + postResponseText;
}
```

Can anyone from Zoho Creator or DocuSign help me figure out what I have to do to get the same result from the Creator app that I get from the DocuSign API tester I linked to above?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your request content-type and request body that you are sending out.  By default, if you do not set the `Content-Type` header in your DocuSign API call then it defaults to `application/json`.  The request body that you are setting...

```
requestBody2 = "{\n \"envelopeDefinition\" : \"{\n  \"-xmlns\" : \"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\",\n =\"xmlns:i\":\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\",\n \"emailSubject\": \"test email subject\",\n  \"emailBlurb\": \"test email blurb\",\n  \"templateId\": \"1D489D22-55D9-4320-8C16-28DE11C4AB09\",\n  \"status\": \"created\",\n  \"messageLock\": \"false\"\n}}";
```

is not valid.  Looks like you are using a combination of xml and json, which DocuSign will not accept.

Have you gone through the [DocuSign Developer Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center)?  If you go through the Quick Start section it eventually leads to the API TOOLS section, which has two important tools that will be of great help here.  I'm guessing based on your code that you are using Python.  As such, check out the API Walkthroughs which have sample Python code for 9 API uses cases, including sending a document from a template:

http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs

For instance, here is the Python code for sending a document from a template:

```
# DocuSign API Walkthrough 01 (PYTHON) - Request Signature from Template
import sys, httplib2, json;

# Enter your info:
username = "***";
password = "***";
integratorKey = "***";
templateId = "***";

authenticateStr = "<DocuSignCredentials>" \
                    "<Username>" + username + "</Username>" \
                    "<Password>" + password + "</Password>" \
                    "<IntegratorKey>" + integratorKey + "</IntegratorKey>" \
                    "</DocuSignCredentials>";
#
# STEP 1 - Login
#
url = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information'   
headers = {'X-DocuSign-Authentication': authenticateStr, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
http = httplib2.Http()
response, content = http.request(url, 'GET', headers=headers)

status = response.get('status');
if (status != '200'): 
    print("Error calling webservice, status is: %s" % status); sys.exit();

# get the baseUrl and accountId from the response body
data = json.loads(content);
loginInfo = data.get('loginAccounts');
D = loginInfo[0];
baseUrl = D['baseUrl'];
accountId = D['accountId'];

#--- display results
print ("baseUrl = %s\naccountId = %s" % (baseUrl, accountId));

#
# STEP 2 - Create an Envelope with a Recipient and Send...
#

#construct the body of the request in JSON format  
requestBody = "{\"accountId\": \"" + accountId + "\"," + \
                "\"status\": \"sent\"," + \
                "\"emailSubject\": \"API Call for sending signature request from template\"," + \
                "\"emailBlurb\": \"This comes from Python\"," + \
                "\"templateId\": \"" + templateId + "\"," + \
                "\"templateRoles\": [{" + \
                "\"email\": \"" + username + "\"," + \
                "\"name\": \"Name\"," + \
                "\"roleName\": \"Role\" }] }";

# append "/envelopes" to baseURL and use in the request
url = baseUrl + "/envelopes";
headers = {'X-DocuSign-Authentication': authenticateStr, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
http = httplib2.Http()
response, content = http.request(url, 'POST', headers=headers, body=requestBody);
status = response.get('status');
if (status != '201'): 
    print("Error calling webservice, status is: %s" % status); sys.exit();
data = json.loads(content);
envId = data.get('envelopeId');

#--- display results
print ("Signature request sent!  EnvelopeId is: %s\n" % envId);
```